# LINQ to SQL: Create a dettached entity object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, detach

I have generated few classes using to LINQ to SQL

one of them being "Customer"

Now I want to create a Customer object that is disconnected.

i.e. I can create the object keep it in session and then attach it back only if I want to. Not automatically. Hence only if I attach it - it should affect my context's SubmitChange() otherwise not.

Is this possible?

Also can I add this detached object to a collection of attached objects without affecting SubmitChanges() or on add will the detached object become attached again?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question, can you give some more information?  It is completely possible to create a disconnected Customer object by just instantiating one with `new`, but it seems like you know that already.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "Detach" method, but it is possible with serialization:

```
Customer customerCopy;
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bf.Serialize(ms, customer);
    ms.Position = 0;
    customerCopy = (Customer)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Be aware that it's cumbersome to re-attach the object afterward.  The `Attach` table method is finicky - you generally need a `Version` (timestamp type) column on the entity in order for it to work.

Note - I just reread your question and it sounds almost as though you simply want to *construct* the object.  If so, constructing a new `Customer` via `new Customer()` will **not** create an attached entity.  It only becomes attached after you invoke the `InsertOnSubmit` or `Attach` method on the table.

Also, you can freely add detached entities to a `List<Customer>` (or similar) containing attached entities - Linq to SQL does not care about this, an entity only becomes attached if it is dispensed by the `DataContext` itself or if you attach it using one of methods above.

Answer (score 0):

For Linq to Sql, only the DataContractSerializer is supported.

There's a more performant way to Detach(), and that's using the following base method:

```
public void Detach()
{
   GetType().GetMethod("Initialize", BindingFlags.Instance |         
      BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(this, null);
}
```

This will call the Initialize() method which will 'reset' all the FK properties. The trick is that this method is only generated when Serialization has been turned on. There's a way to get around this, check [here](http://www.jowenmei.com/?p=555) for more info

Comment: Hi, link to your site doesn't work http://www.jowenmei.com/?p=555, could you please put this post somewhere else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vitaliy, Sorry I lost that blogpost. I do still have the code though.

```
public class EntityBase : IEntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Detaches the entity, so it can be added to another dataContext. It does this by setting
    /// all the FK properties to null/default.
    /// </summary>
    public void Detach()
    {
        // I modified the .tt file to generate the Initialize method by default. 
        // The call to OnCreated() is moved to the constructor.
        GetType().GetMethod("Initialize", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

And here's the call to Detach() from my adapter

```
public class OrderAdapter : IOrderAdapter
{
    public void Add(IOrder order)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new ATPDataContext())
            {
                Order newOrder = (Order)order;
                newOrder.Detach(); // not required for insertion, but to keep references to Product 
                db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(newOrder);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
        }
    }
 }
```

And in my .tt file

```
#region Construction
public <#=class1.Name#>()
{
    Initialize();

    <# if (class1.HasPrimaryKey) {#>
        OnCreated();
    <# } #>
}

private void Initialize()
{
<#        foreach(Association association in class1.Associations) { #>
        <#=association.Storage#> = <#
        if (association.IsMany) {
            #>new EntitySet<<#=association.Type.Name#>>(attach_<#=association.Member#>, detach_<#=association.Member#>);
<#          } else {
            #>default(EntityRef<<#=association.Type.Name#>>); 
<#          }
    }
#>
    }
#endregion
```

HTH!